# Error while fetching data from database laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am new to laravel. I am facing error while i fetch the data from database. But other pages are working (fetching also).

Here is My code for your review.
my contorller :

```
 public function info()
{

    // Show the page
    $data = Customer::all();
    return view('eventlist')->with('data',$data);

}
```

My view :eventlist.blade.php

```
             <tbody>
                @foreach ($events as $user)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!! $user->name !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $user->cname !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $user->sdate !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $user->edate !!}</td>
                        <td>{!! $user->room !!}</td> </tr>@endforeach                        
                </tbody>
```

My route :

Route::get('eventlist', 'MyController@info');`

While i try to fetch the data : It shows the error undefined variable :events

Help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You are looping for wrong variable, look at your this line

```
@foreach ($events as $user)
```

you are looping `$events` and from `controller` you are passing `data` variable. see your this line

```
return view('eventlist')->with('data',$data);
```

**so change your this line**

```
@foreach ($events as $user)
```

**to this**

```
@foreach ($data as $user)
```

everything will be fine